# Is there any way to refer to a function $f$, without defining $f$?

Tags: functions, notation

If I have to refer to a function $f$ without defining it explicitly, what should I write? Or is there no notation I can use but explicitly defining $f$?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a problem here - it is common in advanced math to write about functions you never explicitly defined. It comes with the territory.

Comment: dear my2cents, do you know what the domain and codomain of the function are going to be? if so, (suppose they are $X$ and $Y$, respectively) then you can just say "let $f:X\to Y$ be a function", or "let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$"

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I know the domain and codomain, but is there any way to refer to $f$ without defining it explicitly?

Comment: dear my2cents, perhaps could you clarify what you mean by "defining it explicitly"? (I think of saying "let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$" as not defining $f$ explicitly, but do you have something else in mind?)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I mean saying "Let $f: X\to Y$ be a function" or similar.

Comment: so you're saying you don't want to give the function a name? in that case, you can just say "any function from $X$ to $Y$ has such and such properties", or something along those lines, depending on what you're trying to write

Comment: (perhaps could you give an example of the kind of sentence you are trying to write? it might make what you're looking for more clear :) )

Comment: My sentence is: Let $V=\text{span}(e^{\lambda_1x}, e^{\lambda_2x}, \dots, e^{\lambda_nx})$, and $T: V\to V$ by $Tf=f'$. However, I need to refer to the functions $f_1(x)=e^{\lambda_1x}, \dots, f_n(x)=e^{\lambda_nx}$ as $f_1, ..., f_n$ and not $f_1(x), ..., f_n(x)$. (from linear algebra)

Comment: ahhh, I see; I personally think that it is best for clarity to write something like "for each $i\leqslant n$, define $f_i:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f_i(x)=e^{\lambda_i x}$." but ultimately it's up to you; what you've written in that sentence seems quite clear already to me, although maybe others would disagree

Comment: And then after, if I need to refer to $f_i$, I can just write $f_i$ (e.g. $Tf_i$, which is in my next sentence).

Comment: You could also use a notation like $e^{\lambda(\cdot)}$ or $x \mapsto e^{\lambda x}$ for this purpose.  However I think just defining $f_i$ explicitly as @atticus says would probably be best if you want to refer to them later. You could also use a notation like $f_{\lambda}(x) = e^{\lambda x}$ if you don't want as many indices.

Comment: dear my2cents, yes, that's exactly right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like writing "Let $f: V\to W$ be a function defined by [formula]" or similar is clearest.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you’re looking for is the notation $x \mapsto x^2$ which allows you to write the function $f$ where $f(x) = x^2$ without giving it a name. (This notation also leaves out the domain and codomain which might be fine if they’re clear from context or if you mention them in the surrounding text.)